# If an Event has probably 0.015% change of happening, how many time it has to happen to reach probability around 100% of happening?

Tags: probability

Say every time you go to the casino you have 0.015% change to win the biggest prize, how many time would you have to play in order to have your chances of winning around 100%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never reach a 100% chance of winning. The probability of not winning $n$ times is given by $(1-0.015)^n$. This expression will approach 0 when $n$ goes to infinity, but it will never be $0$ for any finite $n$.

Thus you will reach a chance of 99.999% of winning for some $n$, but never 100%.

Edit: You could calculate the probability of winning at least one of the events after $n$ trials by $1-(1-0.015)^n$. Multiply by 100 to get your answer in percentages.

Comment: for 100 attempts you do `1-(0.9985)^100`? resulting in something close to `14%`?. Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, that will give you the probability of not losing 100 times in a row (thus a win somewhere). You're welcome!